# Pyinstaller gives an error when I install Python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When I try to install I get the following error message. What should I do to fix this?problem? Can I get some help? I haven't been in Python for a long time, and I don't really understand what these mean.

```
     command: 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5hj8yy69'
         cwd: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y8nunuv\pyinstaller
    Complete output (36 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y8nunuv\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y8nunuv\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y8nunuv\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y8nunuv\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y8nunuv\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y8nunuv\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y8nunuv\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y8nunuv\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 0: invalid start byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader.waf-'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader.waf3-'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader.lock-waf'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'news_template.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y8nunuv\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y8nunuv\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ---------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5hj8yy69' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Preparing wheel metadata ... error`
The point is this sentence, a wheel file is missing.
`$pip install wheel -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple`
Maybe try to execute this sentence before executing your previous

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).